# How to handle serial port data?

Tags: c#, .net

Hi i have been working on serial port data receive event handler, i have a windows form through which i am receiving data continuously every 1ms and data format is $,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,...............0. Here $- indicates start of frame & is followed by 72 bits of data containing 0s and a particular bit out of 72 bits is 1 indicating error. In the message format 1 indicates error and 0 indicates no error for performing certain action. So i have to read data from serial port and save it in an array. Once data is saved i have to look for dollar to indicate start of frame and count of 1 through which i can add events accordingly.                                                                                               $,0,1,0,0,0....0,0,0,- message of 72bits wide, 1 in message frame indicates error in device so an event accordingly to it. So can anybody help me how to handle this.

My code:

```
  private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
            List<byte> dataBuffer = new List<byte>();
            var sp = (SerialPort)sender;
             var indata = sp.ReadChar();

             if (indata == 0x24 && dataBuffer.Count == 0)
             {               
                while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
                     dataBuffer.Add((byte)serialPort1.ReadByte());

                ProcessBuffer(dataBuffer);
                 dataBuffer.Clear();
             }           

        }
         int g=0;
        private void ProcessBuffer(List<byte> comBuffer)
        {
             byte[] dataSend = new byte[serialPort1.BytesToRead];
           for (int c = 0; c <= 72; c++)
             {
                 if (comBuffer[c] == 0x01) 
                {
                     g = c;
                 }
             }


         }
```

Comment: Confusing your bits and bytes?

Comment: I would suggest decoupling port listener and an actual processing logic by some queue like `BlockingCollection<byte>` which allows asynchronously adding/reading data.

Comment: @jagadisha - You need to provide some additional technical information for us to really help you.  I would assume what you are actually sending is 72 bytes, but because some of the technical errors in your question, this means there is a major disconnect in attempting to decode what you want to do.  Hans Passant of course is right, your serial connection is going to continue to send data, its up to you to handle the recieve buffer.  The send buffer is handled automatically.

Comment: @leppie: Considering the data in terms of bytes and let me know the solution for it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Ok sir its like this, i am getting a fault indication from a device connected to serial port of my system. The message format from the device is "$,0,0,0,1,0,....0,0". The byte in the message showing 1 is the fault. So once i receive this message i need to decode it and provide suitable warning in the UI.

Comment: @leppie: Its bits of data sorry for the mistake.. So suggest me how to handle this..?

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that you'll get *all* the bytes (or bits) in the DataReceived event handler.  You won't, it will fire when there's only a few bytes available.  You'll need to cope with that, at least by keeping the buffer around between invocations.  Something like this:

```
     private List<byte> dataBuffer;

     private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs ek) {
         var sp = (SerialPort)sender;
         if (dataBuffer == null) {
             // Looking for start byte
             if (sp.ReadByte() != 0x24) return;
             dataBuffer = new List<byte>();
         }
         while (sp.BytesToRead > 0) {
             dataBuffer.Add(sp.ReadByte());
             if (dataBuffer.Count == 72 / 8) {
                 // Got all bytes (or bits, it isn't clear), process it
                 var buf = dataBuffer;
                 dataBuffer = null;
                 ProcessBuffer(buf);
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
```

You'll probably need to fix the "got enough bits" condition, it wasn't clear from your question.  The List isn't that pretty but it is a very good way to ensure that the data stays stable while it is being processed, even if you BeginInvoke to the UI thread.  Only replace with a byte[] when you are sure that only one thread will access it at the same time.

Comment: Sir thanks for the help you are providing, is their any other way like processing the data as and when it is received from the serial port. Like i would like to look for $ in the data stream and once i find it invoke an event to look for 1s in the message, by getting next set of data. If this can be done then it would be well and good. Sorry my English isn't that good and i am new to .net as well.

Comment: I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772162/handling-modbus-rtu-frame-in-c-sharp) related to it can you please see it ?