# Handling modbus rtu frame in c#

Tags: c#, console-application, modbus

I am working on [modbus protocol](https://ipc2u.com/articles/knowledge-base/modbus-rtu-made-simple-with-detailed-descriptions-and-examples/#cmnd) in `C#`. I am able to send a single request and get a response from it. I am using a `DataReceivedHandler` to read from incoming port

```
 public ModBusEngine()
    {
        //serial port settings and opening it
        port.ReadTimeout = 500;

        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        port.Open();

        
       
    }

private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {


        //port.ReadTimeout = 200;
        

        // send request and waiting for response
        // the request needs: slaveId, dataAddress, registerCount 
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes recieved are " + port.BytesToRead);
        try
        {
            receivedBytes = port.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);
            var receiveData = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, receivedBytes);
            var finalData = receiveData.Replace("-", "");

            new Thread(() =>
            {
                SaveData(finalData);
            }).Start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
       
    }
```

I am writing to a port in another method

```
 private void ModbusMethod(Iterations iterations)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Modbuss Scheduling data...");
        try
        {
            var items = new byte[]{ Convert.ToByte(iterations.hex), 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03 };
            //iterations.hex is device id
            var crc = BitConverter.GetBytes(ModRTU_CRC(items, items.Length)); //ComputeChecksum(items);

            var dataItems = items.Concat(crc).ToArray();

            port.BaseStream.Write(dataItems, 0, dataItems.Length);

            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }                      

    }
```

I am successfully able to send are receive a response.

**What I want to do now?**

There are multiple registers from which I can get data from the device. These addresses are not completely in sequential order. For example, see below pictures

[image]
[image]

As shown in the above images addresses from `0000` to `0006` are in a sequence then the register is skipped 3 times and the next address is `0009` after that it's again sequential till the address `003A`. Then again registers are skipped and start from `0100` to `012E` in sequence.

I only want to read certain registers i.e. from `0000` to `0002` than from `000E` to `003A` and finally from `0100` to `012E`. One way is to send the frame one by one and then do the needful with the data. But I want to send them in a single request.

I want to do the following.

1. Combining the request and send it in one frame

   `var req1 = new byte[]{ Convert.ToByte(iterations.hex), 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03 };// msn and meter id`
   `var req2 = new byte[]{ Convert.ToByte(iterations.hex), 0x03, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x46 }; // energy values`
   `var req3 = new byte[]{ Convert.ToByte(iterations.hex), 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48 };// energy values other`

`var items = req1.concat(req2).concat(req3);`

I am not sure that this approach will work or not. I don't know how to do it but I don't want to send the frame one by one as the `handler` is continuously reading the port.

1. Collect all the requests data and then save the data.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite get your idea. Modbus has only one function code to read holding registers, which is function code `0x03`. It supports contiguous read. The only two choices are : 1. read a bulk data from 0x0000~0x012E , or read different areas multiple times. I will write an answer for suggestion.

Comment: @LouisGo The main issue is that all the registers are not in the sequence. For now I have managed to get data till `01 03 00 00 00 61` which includes `meter msn` to `L3 reactive energy half value` if I send the frame `01 03 00 00 00 62` the `meter` stops `responding`

Comment: @LouisGo I am just 9 values away of getting all the required data. But I am stuck

Comment: Just get a larger range of data and get only what you want. It reduce much overhead of communication. Like what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: @LouisGo I am getting the larger range of data and within that range, I am unable to get my required values?

Comment: Please edit your post with question detail... I don't get it. If you request for 0x0000~0x012E, then everything should be in response.

Comment: @LouisGo I am guessing that the frame size is icreasing

Comment: Function code 0x03 will return the length of its response. You should look at the data length it responded. Implementation of device might have limit for framesize.

Answer (score 0):

### Assumption

Detail use case isn't provided, so I'll assume this use case needs to continuously sending read requests and process responses.

---

How to send request?
-----
Not much choice, either read at once or split them into small areas.
It depends on your [baudrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baud) and required probe interval.

Assume a bulk read from 0x000~0x003A + 0x0100~0x012E is T and read from 0x0000~0x012E is 3T.
You may calculate communication time [here](https://www.calculator.org/properties/data_rate.html).

1. If required interval is much greater than 3T, then read from 0x0000~0x012E seems okay for this case.
2. If required interval is near 1~3T, then either increasing baudrate or using multiple bulk read are okay.

My suggestion is to read two area 0x000~0x003A + 0x0100~0x012E as a general case, since at least reduce read time by T.

---

How to design
----
My suggestion is keep repeating send and collect it. It's old school but easy to understand for future maintainer.

Following are pseudo code for a state machine while abstracting send and receive.

```
enum EReadState{
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}
EReadState state = EReadState.First; // I use enum if you have more than two areas need to be read
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent();
void StartPolling()
{
    while(true){
        
        switch( state ){
            case First:
                SendFirstPartRequest();
                break;
            case Second:
                SendSecondPartRequest();
                break;
            case Third:
                SendThirdPartRequest();
                break;
        }
        mre.WaitOne() /  wait for one data received
        // Don't forget implement your break condition
    }
}

void Receive()
{
    var data = ... // get data
    state = setNextState( data ); // If first part is received, set state to second.
    mre.Set(); // Go to next send
}
```

Comment: `mre.WaitOne()` after that which break condition is occurred ?

Comment: `Receive()` would call mre.Set() to let it send next message.